# To run mining_pandas.IPYNB locally

Tags: docplex

I'm using Cplex Studio Community 12.8 on Windows 64.

I've installed docplex using conda install -c ibmdecisionoptimization docplex.

To solve mining_pandas.IPYNB, the current command is:
s1 = mm.solve(url=url, key=key, log_output=print_cplex_log)

How can I run it locally?

Answer (score 1):

I've set the environment variable PYTHONPATH to yourCPLEXhome/python/VERSION/PLATFORM.